# Fortran equivalent of numpy.roll function

Tags: python, numpy, fortran

Python's [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function rolls arrays along an axis. Example:

```
from numpy import roll, array
x = array([[1,0,2],[2,1,9],[5,5,1]])
print(roll(x, 1, axis=0))
```

transforms the matrix `x` into

```
array([[5, 5, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 9]])
```

I try to do this in Fortran by slicing a matrix row and attaching it to the existing matrix:

```
program myfun

implicit none
integer, parameter :: N=3
real, dimension(N,N) :: m
integer :: i, j

m = 0
do i = 1, N
    m(i, i) = 1.0
enddo
m(3,1) = 2
m(3,2) = 9
m(1,3) = 5
m(1,2) = 2
m(2,3) = 5

print *, '', [m(:,N), m]

end program myfun
```

This produces matrix

```
[5, 5, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 9]
[5, 5, 1]  <- need to remove this row (how?)
```

Is this the best way to perform `numpy.roll` in Fortran? If so, how do I delete the last row of the matrix?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I get what you want (I don't speak python) but does [`cshift`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CSHIFT.html) do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, the line `cshift(m, SHIFT=(/-1, -1, -1/), DIM=2)` seems to give me what I need. I'm not a Fortran expert, so not sure what `dim` does.

Comment: `Dim` is the dimension you apply the shift to - if Dim=1 (i,j) -> (i+shift,j) for all j, if dim = 2 (i,j) -> (i,j+shift) for all i with the obvious extension to higher dimensions (and with all the shifts done circularly) - And simply `cshift( m, -1, 2 ) should be enough for your case. Any half decent Fortran book will cover this.

Comment: `[m(:,N), m]` has a section of `m` followed by _all_ of `m` so it's hopefully obvious why you have more output than you expect. However, much more important is that this is a rank-1 array that is constructed: a completely different shape from `m`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking `cshift` is what you want. Below is an example, and you can find more details [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-1/cshift.html)

Program:

```fortran
Program test_cshift

  Use iso_fortran_env, Only : stdout => output_unit
  
  Implicit None

  Integer, Dimension( 1:3, 1:3 ) :: m = Reshape( [ 1, 0, 2,   &
                                                   2, 1, 9,   &
                                                   5, 5, 1 ], &
                                                   Shape( m ) )

  Write( stdout, * ) 'Original'
  Write( stdout, '( 3( 3( i1, 1x ), / ) )' ) m
  Write( stdout, * ) 'After cshift'
  Write( stdout, '( 3( 3( i1, 1x ), / ) )' ) Cshift( m, -1, 2 )

End Program test_cshift
```

Compilation and linking:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fcheck=all -std=f2018 -O -g cshift.f90
```

Testing:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Original
1 0 2
2 1 9
5 5 1

 After cshift
5 5 1
1 0 2
2 1 9

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Just to confirm, in general if I have a NxN matrix `m` then I should write `cshift(m, shift=-1, dim=N-1)` to do the Python equivalent (`numpy.roll(m, 1, axis=0)`). Correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so but I would do some experiments to check. If you think this answers our question I suggest you mark it as correct so others don't try too hard to make new answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Python `numpy.roll` function shifts elements in an array along a specified axis where elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at first.

In Fortran, there isn't a built-in function equivalent to `numpy.roll`. However, you can achieve the same functionality using array slicing and concatenation.

The issue in your Fortran code is that you're appending the last row to the end of the matrix but not removing it from its original position.

Here's a way to do it:

```
program myfun

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N=3
    real, dimension(N,N) :: m, m_new
    integer :: i, j

    m = 0
    do i = 1, N
        m(i, i) = 1.0
    enddo
    m(3,1) = 2
    m(3,2) = 9
    m(1,3) = 5
    m(1,2) = 2
    m(2,3) = 5

    m_new = m(2:N, :)  ! Slice from the second row to the end
    m_new(N, :) = m(1, :)  ! Put the first row at the end.

    print *, m_new

end program myfun
```

In this code, `m(2:N, :)` slices the matrix `m` from the second row to the end, and `m_new(N, :) = m(1, :)` puts the first row of `m` at the end of `m_new`. This effectively "rolls" the matrix rows up by one, similar to `numpy.roll(m, 1, axis=0)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error `Error: Different shape for array assignment  on dimension 1 (3 and 2)` at the line `m_new = m(2:N, :)`

Comment: The numpy roll is written in python.  It's long because you can specjfy a tuple of axes.  Basically it constructs a pair of indexing tuples from slices and indices, and then does a copy, `result[res_index] = a[arr_index]`